I updated to Ubuntu 24.04 and Global Protect VPN(6.2.0-265) stopped working. QTNetwork Error 6, ssl handshake failes
VPN Not Working After Ubuntu Update
After updating Ubuntu, my VPN stopped working and I'm encountering the following error:
Error Message:
SSL handshake failed: Failed to load URL https://gp.******.com/SAML20/SP/ACS. QtNetwork Error 6
I’ve been searching for a solution but haven’t found one yet.
System Details:
Ubuntu Version: 24.04
GlobalProtect Version: 6.2.0-265

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Don't put an answer into your question. Edit your question and leave only the problem description, and post an answer to this question yourself using the answer box.

Noted and done,
thanks.

How to Fix VPN Issues After Updating Ubuntu
Luckily I found the solution and it worked perfectly on my setup! I hope this guide helps someone else facing the same issue.
The solution is based on the instructions provided here.

Steps to Fix the Issue

Open a Terminal
Open a terminal window to begin.

Edit the OpenSSL Configuration File
Run the following command to edit the OpenSSL configuration file with administrator privileges:
sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf


Modify the [openssl_init] Section
Scroll down to the [openssl_init] section. If it exists, ensure it includes the following two lines. If the section doesn’t exist, add it with these entries:
[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

(Tip: Use Shift+Insert to paste text into the terminal or the middle mouse button.)

Update the [ssl_sect] and [system_default_sect] Sections
Scroll further down and add or update the following sections to look exactly like this:
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation


Save and Exit

Press Ctrl+O, then Enter to save your changes.
Press Ctrl+X to exit the editor.


Restart Your Network Service
To apply the changes, either reboot your system or restart the NetworkManager service:
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager



File Example
After completing these steps, my VPN started working flawlessly. If you're struggling with a similar issue, give this solution a try, it might save you a lot of time!
